# netstat showing foreign ports as kubernetes:port. What does this mean?

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, minikube, netstat

I am using a Windows 10 Pro machine.

When I run `netstat`, it is showing `kubernetes:port` as foreign address in active connections.

What does this mean? I have checked and there is no kubernetes cluster running on my machine.

How do I close these connections?

[image]

Minikube status:

```
$ minikube status
host:
kubelet:
apiserver:
kubectl:
```

Comment: may I know why you added `minikube` tag and say there is no kubernetes cluster on your machine?

Comment: I installed minikube to run the kubernetes, then i stopped the minikube and k8s cluster with it. That's why i mentioned.

Comment: What's the output of `minikube status` command ?

Comment: I edited the question with the minikube status.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That happens because of the way `netstat` renders output. It has nothing to do with actual Kubernetes.

I have Docker Desktop for Windows and it adds this to the hosts file:

```
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.43.196 host.docker.internal
192.168.43.196 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

There is a record which maps `127.0.0.1` to `kubernetes.docker.internal`. When `netstat` renders its output, it resolves foreign address and it looks at the hosts file and sees this record. It says `kubernetes` and that is what you see in the console. You can try to change it to

```
127.0.0.1 tomato.docker.internal
```

With this, `netstat` will print:

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6940         tomato:6941            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6941         tomato:6940            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         tomato:40347           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         tomato:40348           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         tomato:40349           ESTABLISHED
```

So what actually happens is there are connections from localhost to localhost (`netstat -b` will show apps that create them). Nothing to do with Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I checked the host file and removed kubernetes reference and now there is no kube as foreign host.

Comment: `netstat -b` saved the day for me. Turned out to be `openvpn.exe` established a connection called `kubernetes:1099` which messes up a default JMX manager

Answer (score 9):

It seems that Windows docker changed your `hosts` file.
So, if you want to get rid of these connections, just comment out the corresponding lines in the `hosts` file.

The `hosts` file on Windows 10 is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and
the records may look something like `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`.
I am pretty sure it will disrupt your docker service on Windows (yet, I am not an expert), so don't forget to uncomment these lines whenever you need to get the docker service back.

Comment: it doesn't get rid of the instances or/and ports. They call themselves cbs:XXXXXX now.
I assume they came bundled with docker. It's strange, that when firefox get's opened, more of these instances appear. Something fishy is going on here.

Comment: I didn't want to remove the docker additions from the hosts file, so I just added a line at the top of the hosts file for `127.0.0.1 localhost` and then connections to localhost were correctly identified by the system name again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it looks like your `minikube` instance is definitely deleted. Keep in mind that in **Linux** or other **nix-based systems** it is totally normal that many processes use network sockets to communicate between each other e.g. you will see many established connections with both local and foreign addresses set to localhost:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:45402         localhost:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:45324         localhost:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:2379          localhost:45300         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:45414         localhost:2379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:2379          localhost:45388         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:40600         localhost:8443          ESTABLISHED
```

`kubernetes` in your case is nothing more than `hostname` of one of your machines/VMs/instances. Maybe the one on top of which you ran your `minikube` you called `kubernetes` and that's why this hostname appears currently in your active network connections. Basically it has nothing to do with running **kubernetes cluster**.

To make it clearer you may `cat` the content of your `/etc/hosts` file and look for the entry `kubernetes`. Then you can compare them with your network interfaces addresses (run `ip -4 a`). Most probably `kubernetes` entry in `/etc/hosts` is mapped to one of them.

Let me know if it clarifies your doubts.

---

#### EDIT:

I've reproduced it on **Minikube** on my linux instance and noticed exactly the same behaviour, but it looks like the ESTABLISHED connections are showing only after successfull `minikube stop`. After `minikube delete` they're gone. It looks like those connections indeed belong to various components of kubernetes, but for some reason are not terminated. Basically closing established network connections is responsibility of the application which creates them and it looks like for some reason minikube is not terminating them.

If you run:

```
sudo netstat -ntp ### important: it must be run as superuser
```

it shows additionally `PID/Program name` column in which you can see by which program specific connection was established. You will see a lot of `ESTABLISHED` network connections belonging to `etcd` and `kube-apiserver`.

First I try to reboot the whole instance. It obviously close all the connections but then I verified a few times and it looks like successfully performed `minikube delete` also closes all connections.

Additionally you may want to check available docker containers by running:

```
docker ps
```

or:

```
docker container ls
```

After stopping the minikube instance it still shows those containers and it looks like the reason why a lot of connections with certain **kubernetes** components** are still shown by `netstat` command.

However after `minikube delete` neither `containers` nor `ESTABLISHED` connections with **kubernetes cluster** components are available any more.

Comment: Okay, I'll check. I am using windows 10 pro not linux.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but if you are using `minikube` or `docker desktop` it basically uses some kind of virtualization and runs your docker containers on top of linux os.

Comment: OK, so you run `netstat` in your `windows command line` or `powershell`, right ?

Comment: Please see my last EDIT.